# importing data from online sharePoint to Azure Blob using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, sharepoint, azure-devops

I need assistance with importing data from online SharePoint to Azure data factory. The error that i am getting is from the copy activity the configuring the source and sink. When having to create a data lake then i keep getting the error creating it.

Error below

[image]

Comment: What is not clear regarding the error? Message seems clear to me.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when the connection to your blob storage is not established correctly.

In your linked service, you can provide the account selection from the subscription or enter it manually.

If you manually provide the connection string in Azure blob storage linked service, provide the storage account name and get the storage account key from Access keys from your storage account instead of getting the whole connection string from the blob account.

[image]

[image]

You can refer this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFfNu3cI-uw) to copy from SharePoint to blob using azure data factory